# Detect whether map has been scrolled or not in mapview

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkmapviewdelegate

How can I detect whether map has been scrolled or not in mkmapview in ios. The delegate method of map is not getting called. please help..

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
  -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

Also make sure your mapView.delegate = self;